# In idiomatic Typescript, should I always declare a variable's type, or should I rely more on type inference?

Tags: typescript, idioms

At first, our team found ourselves writing lots of code like this because that's what we're used to in languages like ActionScript.

```
var arrayOfFoo : Array<Foo> = new Array<Foo>();
//Then, sometime later:
var someFoo : Foo = arrayOfFoo[0];
someFoo.someFooMethod();
```

That's fine, but it can be simplified by relying more heavily on Typescript's type inference:

```
//No need to declare the type ": Array<Foo>" here:
var arrayOfFoo = new Array<Foo>();

//Again, no need to declare that someFoo is a Foo
var someFoo = arrayOfFoo[0];
someFoo.someFooMethod();
```

Typescript is pretty darn good at type inference. If I drop the type from the left-hand side of assignments, the compiler still knows what type that object is, and will still give a compile error if I try to do something on the variable the inferrred type can't do.

I like that it's less code to read, and less code to type. The example that declares types is beginning to feel "redundant" to me, but I'm worried that we might be setting ourselves up for trouble later. I'm curious what the community recommends, if anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type inference vs. explicit type declaration in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911407/type-inference-vs-explicit-type-declaration-in-typescript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I do for my project is not putting the type definition everywhere when it can be inferred because (as you already said) it is redundant.

What I'm currently not doing (but I really want to do it) is compiling with the --noImplicitAny any flag.

With that flag enabled you will get an error where it couldn't infer the type which is really helpful! You might want to look at that! See my example below.

The code below will give three errors when compiled with tsc --noImplicitAny tst.ts:

```
var arr = [];
var x = null;
var a: string[] = [];
var s = a["foo"]
```

tst.ts(1,11): error TS7015: Array Literal implicitly has an 'any' type from widening.

tst.ts(2,5): error TS7005: Variable 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.

tst.ts(5,11): error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.

This way when you doing something weird (accidentally) will give an error.

Comment: Nice - that looks really helpful, and would definitely increase my confidence in relying on type inference more. When I first experimented with the --noImplicitAny fag, I ended up with some errors even in the type definition files I was using. Upon closer examination though, they're easy to fix, and it would result in more explicit code. Thanks!

Comment: This is a pragmatic approach - use the `noImplicitAny` flag and only declare types you have to. It is also worth being explicit with return types for methods as this enhances readability.

Comment: As a side note, type declarations seem to really help IntelliJ 13 perform syntax analysis of the typescript files. There are cases in larger files with fewer declarations where the analysis never complete.

Comment: Can someone explain why implicit any's are bad? I'm brand new to TypeScript.

Comment: @KevinWheeler because implicit any's could be just a place where a dev forgot to declare a real type, and downstream type errors won't get caught by the compiler because the place where the dev forgot is now typed as any, so spelling mistakes when using that implied any-typed variable could lead to runtime errors, defeating the purpose of typescript. --noImplicitAny doesn't mean you can't use `any`, it just means you have to be **explicit** about your any's - i.e. the compiler won't let you "forget" to type a variable (where typescript can't infer the type).