# Type inference vs. explicit type declaration in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've come across several different instances of code where variables are declared with an explicit type even though the inferred type is obvious:

Example: `loading: boolean = false` or `name: string = "John"` or `count: number = 0` etc.

TSLint favors the inferred type over the explicit type, so I'm wondering is this just a stylistic issue? Do these explicit types even matter during runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example it is just about style, hence, it has not impact to your code from compilation perspective. Be aware this is for the cases where the variable value explicitly defines its type, which might make your code complicated to read in cases of resigning values from other variables.

In other words it might be better you do:

```
name: string = "John"
bday: Date = "1980/01/10" //the compiler says there is an error
```

And avoid:

```
name = "John"
bday = "1980/01/10" //no compiling error, but it should be new Date("1980/01/10")
```

Note: Undefined types will always be considered as any.

Comment: While it is true that your date example will not yield an error, if bday should really be a Date, you will want to access some Date properties, or want to use it as a parameter where the parameter will be a Date, which will yield an error. I personally prefer type inference where possible, but it might just be my laziness :)

Comment: My point was to show the possibility of a mistake in both cases. It is very common conditional errors just because of attribute types. I prefer writing as less as possible, but I know it makes my code harder to be read.

Answer (score 8):

Most of today's javascript community would probably support inference motivating their choice by the fact that type inference is somehow easier to read (i.e. less letters) but ease of reading is not only less reading. Less letters is an imprecise metric for program simplicity consider:

`I hp I mk m slf clr` vs `I hope I make myself clear`

Be open try both approaches work your way towards a strong opinion. Yet be flexible and don't let your opinion to stand in your way.

Remember that

> opinion is what I have when I haven't done enough research

If you understand the consequences of one decision over another you don't need an opinion you just choose a more preferable option. In this case you remove yourself from a decision-making process allowing a common sense or logic to dictate the actual shape of the code you write. It may save you at a later point in time from justifying yourself by saying something like "I'm an artist I see things this way".

This line of thinking makes it obvious why it's in most cases a good idea to support your team's decision.

It's bad idea to procrastinate and wait for error to pop in runtime as there is no reason for your program to actually die in agony by exception. It's a lot faster and cheaper to identify an error before you commit and deploy your code as it would take a lot more resources from your team for context switching in terms of creating tickets, planning them, investigating or knowledge sharing them and having them fixed. Likewise it is cheaper from business perspective to not make mistakes as each bug can be measured in loss of revenue so what's the point in even considering a gamble of check by runtime as an option? Just make sure your types are precise and extensive.

This is the reason why I personally tend to prefer explicit types. My list of pros and cons tells me that types are not underwear so no need to hide them. Static type system aligns a formal mathematical proof that your program is correct. And it's there for a reason - support your type system and it will support you in return. Don't be lazy decorate variables with types. Even when type declaration might be seemingly omitted it's still a good idea to provide a typename.

There were many situations when multibillion losses were caused to companies and projects by the lack of type system or its imperfection.

Having a type name before your eyes can help you trigger a second thought and save you from making a mistake even if your compiler isn't strict enough to check (i.e a number is not always a number that you'd might expect consider the following case:

```
const x: Miles = 3;
const y: Kilometers = 5;
...
const result = x + y; // Result type is obviously unknown so the operation shouldn't be implicitly allowed
```

If your types are becoming too big or complex to write each time it's a hint for you that it's time to do something about it.

But who knows I may be wrong, like anyone...

Comment: Always grateful for a considerate and eloquent perspective. Thank you for sharing your insightful thoughts!

Answer (score 4):

Declared types do not matter at all at runtime. When the Javascript is generated all types will be removed since Javascript does not support specifying variable types.

As to why TSLint prefers type inference ove explicit typing I would say it is probably to keep things DRY (don't repeat yourself). Since the compiler can do the typing for you there is no reason to add more noise to the code.

Answer (score 4):

From  [Should you annotate or let TypeScript infer the types?](https://davidgomes.com/annotate-vs-type-inference/)

> The best general guideline for whether to annotate code or not is
> whether the expression/variable you're annotating is a "boundary" or
> not. Boundaries usually refer to the exported functions/classes/etc.
> of your various modules. For these, you likely want to be explicit as
> to what you're expecting to make your APIs more clear.
>
> However, functions and variables **internal** to a specific module likely
> **don't need to be annotated**

From [When to add types and when to infer in TypeScript](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/when-to-add-types-and-when-to-infer-in-typescript/)

> Add types to all function declarations.
>
> not add explicit types to variables

From https://www.schibsted.pl/blog/typescript-type-inference/

> “Ideal TypeScript code includes type annotations for function/method
> signatures but not for the local variables created in their bodies.
> This keeps noise to a minimum and lets readers focus on the
> implementation logic”.