# What is the point of using types when declaring a variable in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm newbie in Typescript, and I know its great benefits when working with big apps and teams : )

Let's suppose I have this TypeScript:

```
declare const num = 5: number;
```

Why is that better than:

```
const num = 5
```

Should I explicitly declare (with type) simple variables always in TypeScript?

Fortunately, the variable’s type is inferred from the data type of the value.
So can I use normal JS (like in the second example)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In idiomatic Typescript, should I always declare a variable's type, or should I rely more on type inference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559636/in-idiomatic-typescript-should-i-always-declare-a-variables-type-or-should-i)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When declaring a variable, if the type of what you're assigning to it can be understood correctly by the TS compiler, then there's no need to define its type. In many cases, declaring an explicit type is not necessary, such as with `const num = 5`. But sometimes it *is* necessary, such as when declaring a variable which will be assigned to later, but not now:

```
let someData: MyData;
```

Otherwise, `someData` will be typed as `any`, which isn't type-safe.

Another example for when it would be useful would be when creating an array which will later be pushed to:

```
const arr: number[] = [];
// later:
arr.push(5);
```

The compiler can't infer *at `arr`'s declaration* what values the array may contain, so `number[]` should be included when defining `arr`. (Otherwise, it'll be typed as `any[]`, and `any` is not type-safe and should be avoided when possible)

Whenever TS *can* infer the type of a variable correctly and automatically - and most of the time, it can - then feel free to leave off the explicit note of the variable type, since it doesn't help.

Note that `declare` does something *completely different* - using that keyword tells TS that a variable with that name is defined in the current scope by *other code*, such as by a library. Variables which are `declare`d will not exist in emitted code. Unless you have a library or something which defines a variable that Typescript doesn't understand exists, you almost certainly don't want to use `declare`.

Answer (score -1):

You are using typescript to avoid wrong value assignment. For instance, typescript will throw an error when you try to use a string for a number variable.

```
let num: number = 5;
```

You can't change it to `num = "this is a string";`. Typescript will throw a type error.

Comment: But TS can already infer that `num` should be *only* a number when you do `let num = 5;`. There's no benefit to the `:number` part, which is the core of OP's question. TS already throws an error when you do `let num = 5; num = "this is a string";`

Comment: The question was to understand why Typescript is useful. I think I answer it correctly.

Comment: OP is asking "Should I explicitly declare (with type) simple variables always in TypeScript?" and why explicitly declaring a type is useful, which your post doesn't address. OP is *not* asking "Why is TS useful".