# How do I define a variable as an enum value type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

In TypeScript, if I have one enum, how do I define a variable that has a type set as one of it's values?

```js
enum Alpha {
  A = 1,
  B = 2
}

const c = 1; // I want to say it's a type of a value of Alpha
```

Comment: const c: Alpha = Alpha.A

Comment: Either @Dai or maybe user5507535 should write that as an answer if it suffices.  If it *doesn't* suffice, what is missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the point of using types when declaring a variable in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074759/what-is-the-point-of-using-types-when-declaring-a-variable-in-typescript)

Comment: @jcalz I feel it's a dupe of the linked question above - or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559636/in-idiomatic-typescript-should-i-always-declare-a-variables-type-or-should-i